# Indipay parameter missing exception

Tags: laravel

I am sending all the parameters required by indipay but still i am getting a parameter missing exception. If i send the static values then it is working fine.

```
$parameters = [
        'purpose' => 'Application Fee for '.$regnId,
        'buyer_name' => $request->s_fname.' '.$request->s_lname,
        'amount' => env('APPLICATION_FEE'),
    ];
    $order = Indipay::prepare($parameters);
    return Indipay::process($order);
```

> IndipayParametersMissingException in InstaMojoGateway.php line 119 at
>   InstaMojoGateway->checkParameters(array('redirect_url' =>
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/parent/response/indipay', 'purpose' =>
>   'Application Fee for GKB_19LKG_000019', 'buyer_name' => 'asdasd
>   asdasd', 'amount' => '200')) in InstaMojoGateway.php line 41

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.
The indipay package didn't gave the correct error. There was no parameter missing in the request. There was a max size issue in the validator function for the instamojo payment gateway.